# What is happening to my pumpkin shoot?

Tags: vegetables, pumpkins

Please find attached picture of my pumpkin shoot. The leaves show a whitish appearance. I am growing it with vermi compost and cocopit mix. Can somebody tell what has been happening with the plant lately? I am very much worried. I am staying in india and currently its a rainy season.[image]

Comment: Is the the thing that bothers you that white mottled flaring pattern around the vein intersections on the newer leaves?  Or are you talking about the yellowish drying of a couple of the older leaves? The newer leaves look healthy. That interesting white/green pattern is pretty typical of a few different squashes. Not sure about the older leaves, but since the new growth looks so good, I don't think you need to worry about this plant.  .. It looks like it is in a pot: don't skimp on the sunlight.

Comment: Thanks. I am concerned on the both, yellowing of the leaves and whitish pattern.. Now i am clear that whitish appearance is some natural pattern, however i don't understand why the leaves turned yellow much sooner.

Comment: @LorelC. Do you say that i shoud not place it in sunlight?

Comment: No, sorry. "Don't skimp on sunlight." I just meant you should give it *lots* of sun. When the plant is rooted in the ground, you can't usually control how much sun it gets, but if it is in a pot, sometimes you can move it to a very sunny place. I wasn't sure from the photo, but maybe the leaves seemed a bit lighter green than they could be. Your little pumpkin looks fine to me, but I'm pretty sure that family of plants just loves sun. So: Yes on Sun.